# How could i use iCarousel in my project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, icarousel

I am a newbie in iphone development and want to implement coverflow. I googled it and came across the opensource iCarousel, but did not understand the way to use it in my project?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, there is a sample application to demonstrate the use, along with the iCarousel classes.

Comment: i am trying it since 3 days, but not getting how the flow is? I have debug the whole example, but could not understand how the "viewForItemAtIndex"  get a call? How can i integrate it in my project ? what are the steps?

Comment: Have you used a UITableView before? It works the same way - set up your view controller as the dataSource for the iCarousel view and implement the numberOfItemsInCarousel and viewForItemAtIndex methods yourself to provide views to the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the zipped file from Github. Unzip and open

> nicklockwood-iCarousel-da1deb7/Examples/Basic\ iOS\
>   Demo/iCarouselExample.xcodeproj

The

> iCarouselExampleViewController

looks just like what your view controller, that is supposed to show the carousel, should look like. Note that the view of your view controller will be a custom view of the type :

> iCarousel

Answer (score 2):

iCarousel.m class calls that function from its dataSource class. set delegate and datasource of iCarousel object. 
At sample application, dataSource and delegate is set by interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through the example provided [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/tree/master/Examples/Basic%20iOS%20Demo)? I didn't try it, but it seems to be straightforward.