# How to integrate the iCarousel -Fading demo project into my project in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios6, coverflow, icarousel

My requirement is to display the Table view as cover flow.I found the Imageview as cover flow using following link.
http://code4app.net/ios/iCarousel-for-Cover-Flow/4f87d2db06f6e79d32000000

But when I downloded and edit the code of UIImageView with UIView in the downloded app,It is working good.But when I create the new application and trying to set the same functionality it does not displayed any thing.

Please tell me How to integrate the iCarousel/Fading Demo project to my own app.

In this link [How could i use iCarousel in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473862/how-could-i-use-icarousel-in-my-project)

they are saying "iCarousel.m class calls that function from its dataSource class. set delegate and datasource of iCarousel object. At sample application, dataSource and delegate is set by interface builder."  How can I do it.

When I debugging it

```
  - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
    {

    }
```

this method is not executed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218377/how-to-display-the-list-of-table-view-as-cover-flow-in-ios6-1/15220578#15220578

y ur not editing the Question if ur requirement ? each time making new Question?

Comment: Answer for that question is perfectly working for me. Whats the problem ur facing?

Comment: When I drag and drop the iCarousel files in to my app and I am trying to create the same functionality of displaying the list of images as cover flow,I didn't  get the output

Comment: Just I grag and drop the iCarousel.h and .m files and I copy the code from iCarouselExampleViewController.m to ViewController.m and change the ViewController.xib as per this.Then also I got the blank out put. when I debugged the code I found - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{} this method is not called?Please tell me where did I made mistake?

Comment: Check ur yester's question regarding Icarosel . Answers is updated.. U need that output exactly right?

Comment: yes that is the exact output

Comment: You need to implement -(NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel: as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy the xibs or make new ones? If you made new ones maybe you forgot to wire up the dataSource and delegate of the iCarousel views in the XIB to your view controller's properties..?

Comment: I display the two buttons in first index of the iCarousel.Can I have the action methods for these two buttons?